# OpenCL Quartus Hardware Generation time consuming

Tags: performance, compilation, opencl, fpga, intel-fpga

I have recently purchased a Nallatech PCI-Express FPGA Board, which I'm developing OpenCL applications for it. My main problem is the extensive compilation time of the OpenCL into the hardware code, which I believe comes from quartus Hardware Generation Stage. For example a really simple OpenCL code takes at least 7 to 8 hours to be finished and ready to deploy.

I don't have a hardware background, specifically working with quartus. All I see is quartus is only utilizing a single core of my server. Is there any way to configure the hardware generation part, in order to utilizing all resources in my machine, in order to boost the building process performance?

Here is a sample code I have for compilation:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable
__kernel void MAdd16(__global double *data, int nIters) {
  int gid = get_global_id(0), globalSize = get_global_size(0);
  double s = data[gid];
  double16 s0 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  for (int j=0 ; j<nIters ; ++j) {
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
 s0=10.0f-s0*0.9899f;
  }
   data[gid] = s0.s0+s0.s1+s0.s2+s0.s3+s0.s4+s0.s5+s0.s6+s0.s7+s0.s8+s0.s9+s0.sa+s0.sb+s0.sc+s0.sd+s0.se+s0.sf;
}
```

Comment: can you write down opencl kernel code? it may have some racecondition or something that make it slower. are you sure that kernel design fits in that chip? what were global and local range values? how much private memory usage per workitem?

Comment: I think you should take advantage of x86 emulators. There is mention of emulator in [here](https://www.altera.com/products/design-software/embedded-software-developers/opencl/overview.html)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Hi. I've added a sample source at the end.

Comment: @kanna The emulator is not running on the real device. I need to check the performance of on the real FPGA. Emulating is good for any compilation or logical error.

Comment: conversion from float to double could be increasing pipeline length such as 0.9899f to type double. also you are doing same thing for s0 element only so it is serialized, can't use wider pipeline for that s0 = 10.0 - 0.9899 part it must have been serialized in background, which also may increase pipeline length. also niter may be too high? how much time does a `c[i]=a[i]+b[i]` cost? if it is higher too, then maybe its fpga "architeture to bitstream generation" which is taking too much time, not "opencl to architecture" part.

Comment: I've heard (from FPGA vendors) that compiling kernels will full optimization can take hours or days. They are trying lots of combinations of hardware to turn software into "hardware."